# AJAX requests is not working (Failed to execute 'open') : Cordova Android

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova 6.3.0 and AJAX requests from Android devices don't work. I have already read and tried anything useful I could find and I am not able to solve this problem myself.

I am using a jquery ajax request to call a server that returns user specific information (simple integers):

```
$.ajax({
    url : ENDPOINT_SERVER_API,      // e.g. http://www.example.com
    async: false,
    success: function(data, status) {
        // display normal UI
        // render view
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I have installed `cordova-plugin-whitelist` and it is listed in the `config.xml` using `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />`.

Additionally, I used and tried multiple different `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" .../>` tags such as:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://example.com:*">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' example.com">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://*.example.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

---

My `config.xml` looks as follows:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

---

The error message that I receive is:

```
{"stack":"Error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest':
    Refused to connect to 'http:\/\/mydomain.com\/?action=get_user_specific_data&user=23afadf83bc3848' 
    because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send (file:\/\/\/android_asset\/www\/lib\/jquery.js:4:14351)
    at Function.n.extend.ajax (file:\/\/\/android_asset\/www\/lib\/jquery.js:4:10579)
    at null.<anonymouse> (file:\/\/\/android_asset\/www\/js\/app.js:63:10)
    at Channel.fire (file:\/\/\/android_asset\/www\/cordova.js:822:23)
    at file:\/\/\/android_asset\/www\/cordova.js:231:49"}
```

---

Now, I also read the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) but can't find any workaround to this problem.

The problem only occurs for android, iOS works like charm.

How can I solve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you allowed cross resource access from server side ?

Comment: I think I do; i added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to the page serving the user specific content.

Comment: how you created build of android ?

Comment: @Hassan Ali: what do you mean? I use `cordova build && cordova run android`

Comment: Just copy paste the www folder and config.xml into new phonegap project. Because i had face this issue that it doesn't added whitelist plugin correctly .

Comment: <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" /> have you added these lines in config.xml

Comment: Yes, I have added these lines and it still doesn't work (updated question with confix.xml. Creating a new project also didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Is there an answer?

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue I added this to the config.xml

```
    <allow-navigation href="*" />

     <access origin="*"/>
```

my html

```
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```